# Issues with Select Query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I've run into a rather weird issue with the select query. First let me explain my set up. I have 5 tables: a user name table, a phone table, a date table, a linking table, and a data table.

My linking table stores all the IDs from the user name table and the number table, along with the date that corresponds with the data in the data table. Below is an example of each table:

```
---UserName---ID---    ---Phone-----ID----     ---Date---     ---rate---charges---Phone-----Date---
|  Bill Jones   1 |    |    123-4567  1  |     |    1/1  |    |  1.24     10      123-4567   1/1
| Mike Jones    2 |    |    456-7895  2  |     |    1/2  |    |  1.00     5       456-7895   1/1
                                                              |  4.56     20      123-4567   1/1
                                                              |  5.34     4       123-4567   1/1
```

And the Linking table looks like this:

```
      ---User ID---Phone ID---Date----
          1          1         1/1
          2          2         1/1 
          1          1         1/1 
          1          1         1/1
```

Now in Access, when I run a select query on user name, phone number, date, and data, I get a set up where the user, phone, and date table join with the link table, while the phone table and date table also join with the data table. it joins things accordingly, and almost works perfect, except I noticed that not all the data actually gets selected. In the real table I have 495 records, but when I run the select query, only 417 get pulled over. Is there a setting or something in Access that I need to change? why would only some of the records get selected? Is this more than likely an error in coding else where? I did notice that If i just did a `select all` of the data table, it pulls over 495 records, but once I start joining the other tables, it messes up.

Here is the select statement:

```
SELECT DATA.[Charges], DATA.[Rate], Date.[ Date], Phone_Master.[ Phone], User_Master.[User Name]
FROM User_Master 
  INNER JOIN ((Phone_Master 
  INNER JOIN DATA 
     ON Phone_Master.[Phone] = Data.[Phone]) 
  INNER JOIN (Date
  INNER JOIN Link_table
     ON Date.[date] = Link.[date])
     ON (Date.[date] = DATA.[date]) AND (Phone_Master.ID = Link.[Phone ID])) 
     ON User_Master.ID = Link.[Username ID];
```

This is the exact setup that MS-Access created for me after I got done joining things in the design view. I have simply changed some of the names to fit my previous example accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide the select statement? Obviously your joins restricts some values. You might use `OUTER JOIN` expression.

Comment: Give me one second and I will update the original post with the select statement

Comment: @MladenUzelac the update has been added

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid Data Model. Your Data table should be linked with other tables with IDs, not your phone. And I suppose because of that your query is so strangely generated (A join within a join).

And why do you have duplicates in the linking table?
And naming tables with spaces is a bad practice.

This is your edited sql query:

```
SELECT DATA.[Charges], DATA.[Rate], Date.[ Date], Phone_Master.[ Phone], User_Master.[User Name]
   FROM User_Master 
     INNER JOIN ((Phone_Master INNER JOIN DATA ON Phone_Master.[Phone] = Data.[Phone]) 
            INNER JOIN (Date INNER JOIN Link_table ON Date.[date] = Link.[date]) 
                ON (Date.[date] = DATA.[date]) AND (Phone_Master.ID = Link.[Phone ID])) 
     ON User_Master.ID = Link.[Username ID];
```

I hope that you see a big mess here.